# Weather from terminal

Tags: command-line

I want to find the current *weather* of a particular city or my location from terminal. Is there any command-line weather app?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Simply enter the following in a terminal:

```
curl wttr.in
```

And will get your location from `/etc/timezone`. Otherwise `curl wttr.in/your_location`. For example, for Tehran:

```
curl wttr.in/tehran
```

Which gives you:

[image: Sample output]

You can also compare two cities:

```
diff -Naur <(curl -s http://wttr.in/london ) <(curl -s http://wttr.in/new-york )
```

Source code of [developer](https://twitter.com/igor_chubin) is available [on Github](https://github.com/chubin/wttr.in).

Comment: Way much better !

Comment: https://github.com/schachmat/wego is not bad for the `devs` between us

Comment: like it, but it threw an error this time:  Sorry, we are running out of queries to the weather service at the moment.  We will get new queries as soon as possible.

Comment: This no longer works - last response was "Follow @igor_chubin for wttr.in updates"

Comment: One word: Nifty! @NightOwlPrgmr For me this works fine as of `2021-05-31`.

Comment: Im also getting nothing but `Follow @igor_chubin for wttr.in updates`

Comment: If anyone needs help processing this text. You need to remove all the ansi escape codes first: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693701/11343425

Comment: Works for me as of July 2022.

Answer (score 20):

Search for your city at http://www.accuweather.com and replace the URL in the following script with the URL for your city:

```
#!/bin/sh

URL='http://www.accuweather.com/en/de/berlin/10178/weather-forecast/178087'

wget -q -O- "$URL" | awk -F\' '/acm_RecentLocationsCarousel\.push/{print $2": "$16", "$12"°" }'| head -1
```

Sample output:

```
Berlin, Germany: Foggy, 1°
```

Comment: But how do I change it to Celcius though

Comment: In the source html, I see `acm_RecentLocationsCarousel.push({name:"Berlin, Germany", daypart:'day', href:'/en/de/berlin/10178/weather-forecast/178087', icon:'i-6-l', bg:'c', temp:'0',  realfeel:'-6',  text:"Mostly cloudy"});`. Using your code, the `awk`field separator is ' ' (space). Is `$12` (temperature) the 12th column?

Comment: My fault, the `awk` separator is `'`. The api uses 2 numbers, the first one is the `postleitzahl` or zipcode. The second seems to be an api code number

Comment: Does not work anymore, has Accuweather API changed?

Answer (score 20):

Here's a great semi-graphical command line utility written in Go:

https://github.com/schachmat/wego/

You'll need to install Go and setup some API stuff, but the instructions are there. Here's a sample pic:

[image]

Comment: This is being publicly hosted now - with IP address to region mapping. Try: curl -4 http://wttr.in

Comment: @jschrab: And you don't need -4 actually. `curl wttr.in` is enough

Comment: Metric units are also available on the publicly hosted version, like so: `curl wttr.in/Helsinki?m`

Comment: If you need metric, don't forget to escape the question mark like this `curl wrrt.in/Helsinki\?m` or place the URL in single quotes like this `curl 'wttr.in/Helsinki?m'`

Answer (score 15):

I have got one more way .

Open your `.bashrc` file and then paste this code at the bottom

```
weather(){ curl -s "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/ForecastXML/index.xml?query=${@:-<YOURZIPORLOCATION>}"|perl -ne '/<title>([^<]+)/&&printf "%s: ",$1;/<fcttext>([^<]+)/&&print $1,"\n"';}
```

Then save & close your `.bashrc` file.

now type `bash` to update the file.

then type

```
weather <location name>
```

for example

```
august@august-OEM:~$ weather guntur
December 14, 2013: Clear. High 31&amp;deg;C (87&amp;deg;F). Winds 0 kph North
December 15, 2013: Clear. High 29&amp;deg;C (84&amp;deg;F). Winds 10 kph NNW
December 16, 2013: Clear. High 31&amp;deg;C (87&amp;deg;F). Winds 10 kph North
December 17, 2013: Clear. High 29&amp;deg;C (84&amp;deg;F). Winds 7 kph ENE
December 18, 2013: Scattered Clouds. High 29&amp;deg;C (84&amp;deg;F). Winds 3 kph ENE
December 19, 2013: Scattered Clouds. High 29&amp;deg;C (84&amp;deg;F). Winds 3 kph ENE
```

Comment: Nice with weather forecast. +1 from me.

Comment: This no longer works, the last dates it shows is from May 2015 (for Cape Town, South Africa at least). Closer examination of the xml output reveals the txt_forecast parent has not been updated since May 2015 while the simpleforecast element seems to have the latest data.

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: Replace YOUZIPORLOCATION with $1 if you want weather <location name> to work

Comment: When I replace `YOUZIPORLOCATION` with `$1` and pass `20001` (Washington, DC zipcode), I get lines that look unformatted like
```Today: Mostly sunny and breezy. Highs in the upper 30s. Northwest winds 20 to 25 mph with gusts up to 45 mph.``` When I use `"washington.dc"`, I get table output `May 4, 2015: Clear. High 32&amp;deg;C (89&amp;deg;F). Winds 43 kph East`. Any idea why the difference?

Comment: This seems to work fine now.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The api is no longer free and there once was the option to apply for a free key for limited use but this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 10):

`ansiweather`

AnsiWeather is a Shell script for displaying the current weather conditions in your terminal, with support for ANSI colors and Unicode symbols. Weather data comes from the OpenWeatherMap free weather API.

```
sudo apt-get install ansiweather
ansiweather -l London,GB -f 3
London forecast => Sat Jan 13: 7/2 °C ☔ - Sun Jan 14: 4/1 °C ☔ - Mon Jan 15: 9/6 °C ☔
```

https://github.com/fcambus/ansiweather

Answer (score 7):

Another a program that comes pre-installed with Ubuntu called `inxi` will give you all types of stats on your computer as well as a weather output.

command: `inxi --help`

command: `inxi -w`

```
        Conditions: 82 F (28 C) - Clear Time: May 13, 10:52 AM CDT
```

command: `inxi -wxxx`

```
     Conditions: 82 F (28 C) - Clear Wind: From the SW at 13 MPH Humidity: 60%

       Pressure: 29.99 in (1016 mb) Heat Index: 84 F (29 C)
       Location: city (USA) Altitude: 185 m
       Time: May 13, 10:52 AM CDT (America/Chicago) Observation Time: May 13, 9:54 AM CDT
```

Comment: Seems that inxi is not part of ubuntu, as of 10.04, but can be installed with `sudo apt install inxi`

Comment: Yes, `inxi` is available but you need to enable the universe repository first.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to install the weather-util package, to do that just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install weather-util
```

You’ll need your [local weather code](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/tg/siteloc.php).

After installation you can run `weather -i <code>`. The code you get from the link above.  For a list of available options, you can run `weather`<sup>[Weather info](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/02/weather-information-in-linux-terminal.html)</sup>

Comment: it shows `Last updated Dec 11, 2013 - 07:00 AM EST / 2013.12.11 1200 UTC
   Temperature: 86 F (30 C)`.is there no way to know the current weather.

Comment: Depending on your location that could be the current info that's available.

Comment: I just tried this and discovered that it is easier to use now: `weather YOURLOCATIONNAME` It searches for your location then and provides possibly multiple results. From these you can read the station identifier which you can use as argument to fetch your weather informations from

Comment: It looks like the service it depends on has been discontinued. I just installed version 2.0, and `weather LAX` (which should show the weather for Los Angeles International Airport) shows a 404 error for http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KNKX.TXT

Comment: That particular data file has moved from [here](http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KNKX.TXT) to [here](http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data/observations/metar/decoded/KNKX.TXT). It should be possible to update the data files, changing each occurrence of `http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data` to `http://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/data`. UPDATE: Looks like they've already fixed it in version 2.1, which you can get from [the project site](http://fungi.yuggoth.org/weather/).

Comment: Users outside of the US should read `weather-util`s description though: _"[...] providing data for localities throughout the United States of America and some select locations globally [...]"_

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com
```

Comment: This seems to be US-only?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in '22

Answer (score 4):

## Meteogram of all mayor cities in the world

`finger city_name@graph.no`

```
$ finger cologne@graph.no

           -= Meteogram for germany/north_rhine-westphalia/cologne =-           
 'C                                                                   Rain
 16                                                                   
 15                           ^^^                                     
 14                  ======^^^   ^^^                                  
 13               ===               ^^^===^^^===                      
 12                                             =========             
 11            ===                                       ====--       
 10      ======                                                ---    
  9=====|                                                         --- 3 mm 
  8     |  |                                                          2 mm 
  7  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |              |     |  |  |  |  |          1 mm 
   _08_09_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 Hour
 
    SE SE SE SE SE SW SW  W  W  W  W SW  W  W  W  W  W NW NW NW  N  N Wind dir.
     5  5  5  5  4  4  5  6  6  6  5  5  5  4  4  5  5  5  4  3  3  3 Wind(mps)

Legend left axis:   - Sunny   ^ Scattered   = Clouded   =V= Thunder   # Fog
Legend right axis:  | Rain    ! Sleet       * Snow
[Weather forecast from yr.no, delivered by the Norwegian Meteorological Institute and the NRK.]
```

Adding `~$(tput cols)` automatically adapts the graph width to the number of columns available in the shell. The forecast will look further into the future on wide shells.

```
$ finger cologne~$(tput cols)@graph.no
```

Here is further information about how to use it:

```
$ finger help@graph.no

yr.no is having technical problems, or you specified an unknown location.

Usage:

 * finger <city name>@graph.no (world weather forecast, no spaces)
   Example: finger newyork@graph.no 

 Advanced usage:

 * finger o:<city name>@graph.no (a one-line forecast)
   Example: finger o:newyork@graph.no 

 * finger ^<city name>@graph.no (Imperial units)
   Example: finger ^newyork@graph.no 

 * finger <city name>+5@graph.no (forecast from 5 hrs ahead in time (max:26))
   Example: finger northpole+5@graph.no 

 * finger <city name>~160@graph.no (set screen width)
   Example: finger southpole~160@graph.no 

 * finger <city name>%2@graph.no (forecast for every second hour [Norway])
   Example: finger oslo%2@graph.no 

 * finger <post code>@graph.no (norwegian weather forecast)
   Example: finger 0458@graph.no 

 Other: 

 * finger news@graph.no (latest headlines from NRK)
 * finger time@graph.no (server local time)
 * finger date@graph.no (server local date)
 * finger about@graph.no (contact information)

International names comes from http://fil.nrk.no/yr/viktigestader/verda.txt.
```

The [story behind this](https://0p.no/2014/12/13/graph_no___weather_forecast_via_finger.html) from the developer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with ICAO station names and METAR weather information from an airport.

`sudo apt install metar`

and check your preferable airport to get the data from
https://www.world-airport-codes.com/
Example for Tokyo International airport/ Haneda = RJTT

`metar -d rjtt`

Sample output

```
RJTT 302000Z 34009KT 9999 FEW030 BKN050 14/08 Q1025 NOSIG  
Station       : RJTT  
Day           : 30  
Time          : 20:00 UTC  
Wind direction: 440 (NNE)  
Wind speed    : 9 KT  
Wind gust     : 9 KT  
Visibility    : 9999 M  
Temperature   : 14 C  
Dewpoint      : 8 C  
Pressure      : 1025 hPa  
Clouds        : FEW at 3000 ft  
                BRK at 5000 ft  
Phenomena     :
```

Unlike `weather` command, this doesn't understand name of cities or countries. Instead of that feature, this can load quicker and multiple places at once.

Answer (score 2):

I have got one more way .

Open your .bashrc file and then paste this code at the bottom

```
test -f ~/.wttr.in || curl -sk wttr.in -o ~/.wttr.in
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -name .wttr.in -cmin +5 -exec curl -sk wttr.in -o ~/.wttr.in \;
head -7 ~/.wttr.in | tail -5
W(){ find ~ -maxdepth 1 -name .wttr.in -cmin +5 -exec curl -sk wttr.in -o ~/.wttr.in \;; head -27 ~/.wttr.in; }
```

Save & close your `.bashrc` file and run the following command to update bash:

```
. .bashrc
```

then type `W` upper case

Comment: bash: W: command not found

Comment: After edit .bashrc relogin

Comment: You don't have to relogin if you "source" your `.bashrc` file. You can run: `source .bashrc` or you can run this  instead: `.  .bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

For even shorter weather output openweathermap.org provides weather data in json format.

The filds from the JSON can then be obtained with a JSON parser like jq i.e..

I wrote a q&d weather-fetch script, wich gets the current temperature, icon and description of weather, then stores a unicode symbol corresponding to the icon and outputs it like

**☂ 6°C**

I regularly update via cronjob and then use the output in my tray status.

An API-key is needed for openweathermap - you may send 1000 requests free of charge per day.

The JSON contains further fields, i.e. forecast data, wind etc. – you can parse them, too, if you want. A description of the API can be found at https://openweathermap.org/current#one .

Unfortunatly some weather symbols are not represented in the Ubuntufont… feel free to adjust.

Here's my script. Change location if you don't life in Hamburg,DE and replace dummy value with your API-key. Depends on curl and jq.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#☁☂☔❄❅❆☃ ☀☁☂⚡⚐☼⛅☇☈☾

#settings - adjust
APIKEY="DUMMY"
LAT="53.618814544576594"
LON="10.131139271164836"
#build query url
QUERY="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="$LAT"&lon="$LON"&appid="$APIKEY"&units=metric"
# write json to variable
WEATHER_JSON=$(curl -Ls "$QUERY")
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  exit 0
fi
# get fields from xml via xmllint | xargs for trimming
# weather description
WEATHER_TEXT=$(jq -r '.weather | .[0] | .description' - <<<"$WEATHER_JSON" | xargs);
WEATHER_ICON_CODE=$(jq -r '.weather | .[0] | .icon' - <<<"$WEATHER_JSON" | xargs);
# temperature
WEATHER_TEMPERATURE=$(jq -r '.main | .temp' - <<<"$WEATHER_JSON" | cut -d '.' -f 1 | xargs);

# set $WEATHER_SYMBOL according to $WEATHER_TEXT
if   [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "01d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☼"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "01n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☾";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "02d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="⛅";elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "02n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☁";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "03d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☁"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "03n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☁";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "04d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☁"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "04n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☁";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "09d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☔"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "09n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☔";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "10d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☂"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "10n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="☂";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "11d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="⚡"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "11n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="⚡";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "13d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="❄"; elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "13n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="❄";
elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "50d" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="⛆";elif [ "$WEATHER_ICON_CODE" == "50n" ]; then WEATHER_SYMBOL="⛆";
# if unknown icon, set text instead of symbol
else WEATHER_SYMBOL="$WEATHER_TEXT";
fi
# output <symbol><space><temp-in-°C>
echo "$WEATHER_SYMBOL"" ""$WEATHER_TEMPERATURE""°C";
exit 0;
```

EDIT 2022-07-09: Since tuxnet24.de does not provide weather anymore. I changed the provider to openweathermap. (this also involves json beeing parsed instead of xml in the former version) /EDIT

Comment: redirection unexpected error

Comment: Switching shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` fixed for me, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: 403 Forbidden error

Comment: rewrote script to use non-404-service. thanks for pointing out, @SurpriseDog

Answer (score 2):

You can compare cities using:

```
diff -Naur <(curl -s http://wttr.in/london ) <(curl -s http://wttr.in/new-york )
```

as illustrated in the top-voted answer. `wttr.in` also makes a great "splash" screen every time you open the terminal. Do this by adding it to your `~/.bashrc` file. I've done that to include Weather, Date, Time and Distribution information as detailed in this answer: [How can I get this terminal splash screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-terminal-splash-screen)

[image: Bash Splash in Windows 10.png]

Sorry I was in Ubuntu in Windows 10 WSL for Spring 2018 updates when I captured this image. Promise I'll boot back into Ubuntu in Linux soon.

Answer (score 1):

I've just made a quick endpoint that returns the weather, along with some more metrics:

```
curl https://curl-weather.herokuapp.com/
```

Note that it currently only displays the weather for London (UK). Here's the Github repo in case you'd like to clone or open issues: https://github.com/nkhil/weather-script

Answer (score 0):

Although accuweather curl solution is pretty good I needed something more informational, so I created simple bash script that pulls info for next 4 hrs from weather.com website. As in previous example you have to modify link for your location.

```
Example output:
$ ./getWeather.sh
Temperature for 1 AM : 65&deg;F and outside should be: Partly - Cloudy FEELS LIKE:   65&deg;
Temperature for 2 AM : 65deg;F and outside should be: Partly - Cloudy FEELS LIKE: 65deg;
Temperature for 3 AM : 63deg; and outside should be: Partly - Cloudy FEELS LIKE: 63deg;
Temperature for 4 AM : 62deg; and should be: Mostly - Clear FEELS LIKE: 62deg;
```

Full script is located at:
https://sites.google.com/site/wozoopalinux/home/wzbash001/get-weather-information-from-command-line-for-next-4-hrs