# Terminal splash screen with Weather, Calendar, Time & Sysinfo?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, ascii-art

I saw a Ubuntu Bash under Windows 10 terminal splash screen here: [Windows Subsystem for Linux display Linux distribution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978977/windows-subsystem-for-linux-display-linux-distribution/978978#978978)

[image: WSL Bash screeny]

How can I change my `~/.bashrc` to get a similar splash screen in regular Ubuntu that would look like this?:

[image: Terminal Splash Screen]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## `now` bash script

**NOTE:** Updated April 28, 2018 for **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

The heavy lifting is the splash component that shows this:

```
$ now
 
Weather report: Edmonton               March 2018            ┌────────────────────────────┐
                                  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa       │   ┏━┓╺┓  ┏━┓┏━┓   ┏━┓┏┳┓   │
     \   /     Sunny                           1  2  3       │   ┃┃┃ ┃ ╹┏━┛┗━┫   ┣━┛┃┃┃   │
      .-.      -23--14 °C          4  5  6  7  8  9 10       │   ┗━┛╺┻╸╹┗━╸┗━┛   ╹  ╹ ╹   │
   ― (   ) ―   ↘ 22 km/h          11 12 13 14 15 16 17       └────────────────────────────┘
      `-’      14 km              18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
     /   \     0.9 mm             25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Yes it really is -14 in Edmonton and feels like -23. A good time to spend the long-weekend inside playing the newly arrived Tomb Raider 2013! Maybe brush up on that Resume to move to Vancouver or Montreal...

Here is the code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: now
# PATH: $HOME/bin
# DESC: Display current weather, calendar and time
# CALL: Called from terminal or ~/.bashrc
# DATE: Apr 6, 2017. Modified: May 24, 2019.

# UPDT: 2019-05-24 If Weather unavailable nicely formatted error message.

# NOTE: To display all available toilet fonts use this one-liner:
#       for i in ${TOILET_FONT_PATH:=/usr/share/figlet}/*.{t,f}lf; do j=${i##*/}; toilet -d "${i%/*}" -f "$j" "${j%.*}"; done

# Setup for 92 character wide terminal
DateColumn=34 # Default is 27 for 80 character line, 34 for 92 character line
TimeColumn=61 # Default is 49 for   "   "   "   "    61 "   "   "   "

# Replace Edmonton with your city name, GPS, etc. See: curl wttr.in/:help
curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0 --silent --max-time 3 > /tmp/now-weather
# Timeout #. Increase for slow connection---^

readarray aWeather < /tmp/now-weather
rm -f /tmp/now-weather

# Was valid weather report found or an error message?
if [[ "${aWeather[0]}" == "Weather report:"* ]] ; then
    WeatherSuccess=true
    echo "${aWeather[@]}"
else
    WeatherSuccess=false
    echo "+============================+"
    echo "| Weather unavailable now!!! |"
    echo "| Check reason with command: |"
    echo "|                            |"
    echo "| curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0    |" # Replace Edmonton with your city
    echo "|   --silent --max-time 3    |"
    echo "+============================+"
    echo " "
fi
echo " "                # Pad blank lines for calendar & time to fit

#--------- DATE -------------------------------------------------------------

# calendar current month with today highlighted.
# colors 00=bright white, 31=red, 32=green, 33=yellow, 34=blue, 35=purple,
#        36=cyan, 37=white

tput sc                 # Save cursor position.
# Move up 9 lines
i=0
while [ $((++i)) -lt 10 ]; do tput cuu1; done

if [[ "$WeatherSuccess" == true ]] ; then
    # Depending on length of your city name and country name you will:
    #   1. Comment out next three lines of code. Uncomment fourth code line.
    #   2. Change subtraction value and set number of print spaces to match
    #      subtraction value. Then place comment on fourth code line.
    Column=$((DateColumn - 10))
    tput cuf $Column        # Move x column number
    # Blank out ", country" with x spaces
    printf "          "
else
    tput cuf $DateColumn    # Position to column 27 for date display
fi

# -h needed to turn off formating: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013954/bash-substring-stringoffsetlength-error/1013960#1013960
cal > /tmp/terminal1
# -h not supported in Ubuntu 18.04. Use second answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1028566/307523
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40\60-\136\140-\176' < /tmp/terminal1  > /tmp/terminal

CalLineCnt=1
Today=$(date +"%e")

printf "\033[32m"   # color green -- see list above.

while IFS= read -r Cal; do
    printf "%s" "$Cal"
    if [[ $CalLineCnt -gt 2 ]] ; then
        # See if today is on current line & invert background
        tput cub 22
        for (( j=0 ; j <= 18 ; j += 3 )) ; do
            Test=${Cal:$j:2}            # Current day on calendar line
            if [[ "$Test" == "$Today" ]] ; then
                printf "\033[7m"        # Reverse: [ 7 m
                printf "%s" "$Today"
                printf "\033[0m"        # Normal: [ 0 m
                printf "\033[32m"       # color green -- see list above.
                tput cuf 1
            else
                tput cuf 3
            fi
        done
    fi

    tput cud1               # Down one line
    tput cuf $DateColumn    # Move 27 columns right
    CalLineCnt=$((++CalLineCnt))
done < /tmp/terminal

printf "\033[00m"           # color -- bright white (default)
echo ""

tput rc                     # Restore saved cursor position.

#-------- TIME --------------------------------------------------------------

tput sc                 # Save cursor position.
# Move up 8 lines
i=0
while [ $((++i)) -lt 9 ]; do tput cuu1; done
tput cuf $TimeColumn    # Move 49 columns right

# Do we have the toilet package?
if hash toilet 2>/dev/null; then
    echo " $(date +"%I:%M %P") " | \
        toilet -f future --filter border > /tmp/terminal
# Do we have the figlet package?
elif hash figlet 2>/dev/null; then
#    echo $(date +"%I:%M %P") | figlet > /tmp/terminal
    date +"%I:%M %P" | figlet > /tmp/terminal
# else use standard font
else
#    echo $(date +"%I:%M %P") > /tmp/terminal
    date +"%I:%M %P" > /tmp/terminal
fi

while IFS= read -r Time; do
    printf "\033[01;36m"    # color cyan
    printf "%s" "$Time"
    tput cud1               # Up one line
    tput cuf $TimeColumn    # Move 49 columns right
done < /tmp/terminal

tput rc                     # Restore saved cursor position.

exit 0
```

Save the `~/.bashrc" file changes.

To display the Ubuntu information you need `screenfetch`:

```bash
sudo apt install screenfetch
```

There are similar display packages to `screenfetch` so shop around!

If you want the same command prompt with "─────────" dividing line between commands, change these lines:

```bash
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Note the length of the separator line coincides with width of `screenfetch` output. In this case it is 92 characters wide and `gnome-terminal` preferences are set accordingly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75410/discussion-on-answer-by-wineunuuchs2unix-how-can-i-get-this-terminal-splash-scre).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix can you make now bash scrip a github repository please? i have few sugestions to make it more resiliant againts resizing terminal window (on hard endline wraping teminals like wsl) and few sugestions how improve calendar to include suport for multiple languages my modified version is bit diferent but is scalable :D

Comment: very nice widget !! thanks. for me, i'm using `tput cub "$(awk '{print length($0)}' <<< "${cal}")"` instead of `tput cub 22` for cal, which is move cursor right according to current line length. I've noticed that the `cal` in Linux have 2 extra whitespace, and max line length is `22`, but in osx, there's no 2 extra spaces, and max line length is `20`. [check here for more details](https://github.com/marslo/dotfiles/blob/main/.marslo/bin/now#L79)

Comment: @Marslo Nice adding support for Mac users. Thanks for putting credit on your link.

Comment: very nice widget !! thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix. You deserve it :)

Comment: @Marslo I will add this widget to my website pippim.com where there are even better widgets.

Comment: pippim.com, the very nice website :) for now, I'm also using the [iweather](https://github.com/marslo/dotfiles/blob/main/.marslo/bin/iweather) as backup weather if `wttr.in` not working ( it's unstable recently ), getting weather info from `api.openweathermap.org`. you can `export OWM_API_TOKEN=...` first

Comment: @Marslo I developed weather for Conky too: https://www.pippim.com/2019/11/24/how-can-i-get-Conky-to-display-weather_.html In Conky it's running all the time and refreshes every five minutes pretty much without errors.

Comment: super ! thanks for letting me know