# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Dual Monitor Unknown Display

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Hello I Have been using Ubuntu two years now and i finally decided to treat myself and get two identical `Acer R240HY 1920x1080 Monitors`. Everything works as intended with only one monitor. As soon as I restart my computer with the second monitor attached to the dvi splitter the the display settings  show `Unknown Display` and that the locked resolution is `1024x768`

I have tried deleting the monitors.xml config file and it didn't work. I tried downloading any proprietary drivers, which did not work. After failed attempts to install Radeon services and drivers: I reinstalled Ubuntu twice.

My neofetch is:

`____________.-/+oossssoo+/-.               adamkali@Azimov 
         :+ssssssssssssssssss+:            --------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: OptiPlex 990 01 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 4.18.0-25-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 18 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1653 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 4.4.19 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 3.28.3 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: GNOME Shell 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Ubuntu-mono-dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-2600 (8) @ 3.800GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7470/8470 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 1685MiB / 15996MiB 
         :+ssssssssssssssssss+: 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.`

Any help would be appreciated.

*EDIT*

As requested here is a link to the dvi splitter that I am trying to use:

- [StarTech.com 1ft DVI Splitter Cable - M / F - DVI-D to 2x DVI-D Dual Video Splitter for Your Split Screen Computer Monitor (DVISPL1DD)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00111EMMO)

I also tried to check my error logs on a whim and found that there are many errors like so:

```
Jul  6 15:48:33 Azimov kernel: [  187.392635] [drm:radeon_dvi_detect [radeon]] *ERROR* DVI-I-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID
Jul  6 15:48:33 Azimov kernel: [  187.675779] rfkill: input handler disabled
Jul  6 15:49:36 Azimov kernel: [  250.219737] radeon_dp_aux_transfer_native: 158 callbacks suppressed
```

I wonder if this could be a kernel issue or something. Thank you to any and all.

Comment: Just a comment that `screenfetch` gives a different splash screen you may prefer over `neofetch`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/terminal-splash-screen-with-weather-calendar-time-sysinfo/1020693#1020693 Do you have a link to this "DVI splitter"?

Comment: Edited in the dvi splitter product page. Thank you! Tried out the screenfetch. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Before buying on Amazon I check the user reviews. The dvi splitter in question only gets 2.6 stars out of 5. In particular this question was asked:

- ***Will this product work with 720p, 1080i, or 1080p signals?***

And the responses (from your point of view) are not good:

[image: dvi splitter.png]