# how can i get Conky to display weather?

Tags: 18.04, conky, weather

I've been strugling to get conky to show the weather, I just installed it and found out that yahoo discontinued the api url which was the one the conky theme was using (http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1103816&u=c), I've tried changing the url to  accuweather and openweather ones and nothing. I just don't understand how this works at all and I have no clue how to get it to work properly, here's the code:

```
##Weather
${image .jelly-weather-icons/conky_icons/circle2.png -s 190x190}
${texeci 1300 curl -s "http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp\?metric\=${METRIC}#\&locCode\=$LOCCOD" -o #~/.cache/weather.xml}
${voffset -110}${offset 425}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=20}${execi 1300 grep #"yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | #grep -o "[^\"]*"}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=8}${voffset -16}o${voffset 14}${font}#${color1}
${execi 1300 cp -f .weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o #"code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image #~/.cache/weather.png -p 425,23 -s 35x35}
${offset 420}${voffset -105}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:size=14} Sevilla
```

btw I found nothing on the internet that could help me out... thanks in advance :)

Edit1: Here is the api that the conky theme saves in the cache/weather.xml
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=6361046&APPID=6be5e3a6e62680c28044791e8fc7b568
I'm slowly understanding how it works

Edit2: This is how the code looks now, I noticed I mistyped some # trying to comment the whole weather part. I just don't understand how conky reads xml (I don't know how to read xml myself but I suppose I can solve that with a few guides of xml :P)

```
##Weather
${image .jelly-weather-icons/conky_icons/circle2.png -s 190x190}
${texeci 1300 curl -s "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=6361046&APPID=6be5e3a6e62680c28044791e8fc7b568&units=metric" -o ~/.cache/weather.xml}
${voffset -110}${offset 425}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=20}${execi 1300 grep "weather:description" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "temp=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*"}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=8}${voffset -16}o${voffset 14}${font}${color1}
${execi 1300 cp -f .weather-icons/$(grep "yweather:condition" ~/.cache/weather.xml | grep -o "code=\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "\"[^\"]*\"" | grep -o "[^\"]*").png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image ~/.cache/weather.png -p 425,23 -s 35x35}
${offset 420}${voffset -105}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:size=14} Sevilla
```

Edit3: So I finally got it working thanks to [@WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) and [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) , this is how the code finally looks for anyone who wants to use it in their conky code:

```
##Weather

${voffset -80}${offset 435}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=20}${execi 1300 curl -s "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=6361046&APPID=6be5e3a6e62680c28044791e8fc7b568&units=metric" | jq -r '.list[0].main.temp' | awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}'}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=8}${voffset -16}o${voffset 24}${font}${color1}
${execi 1300 cp -f .iconos/$(curl -s "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=6361046&APPID=6be5e3a6e62680c28044791e8fc7b568&units=metric" | jq -r '.list[0].weather[].icon').png ~/.cache/weather.png}${image ~/.cache/weather.png -p 425,20 -s 60x60}
${offset 420}${voffset -115}${font ITC Avant Garde Gothic Pro:bold:size=14} Sevilla
```

Basically what it does is read a json from the openweather url using `curl`, and with `jq` search for the values of `.list[0].weather[].icon` and `.list[0].main.temp` as for the temperature it outputs a value with 2 decimal digits which I cut out for personal preferences using `awk '{printf("%.0f\n", $1)}'` the rest of the code is just conky's way to understand where you want it and how you want it. If you want to use it for yourself just change `Sevilla` for your city, and change `curl -s "...your location api url..."` note that if you use a different site for your api url you will have to change `jq` to fit the new json data. Also note that you will have to create a folder with all the icons from this [icon list](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions) or use your own icons but remember to use the same naming (01d.png, 02d.png, ...) and also don't forget to edit this `${execi 1300 cp -f .iconos/$(curl -s "http:/...` and replace `.iconos/` with the directory of your folder.

[Here](https://github.com/carmamo/Juicy) if you want to try out the conky theme

Comment: This is a great Conky resource: http://ifxgroup.net/conky.htm. Another option would be to use **inxi**.

Comment: Can you provide a screen mock up of how weather should be presented?

Comment: All these services will require you to register in order to get an api key. It looks like the Maybe this will help: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ or https://openweathermap.org/api or https://developer.accuweather.com/. Once you have a 'developer' account you can start pulling data from the sites. The code you have above, most likely, will not work without some editing. Show us what you want then we can help you get there.

Comment: I haven't used `conky` in years, but I recall using detail from a local files years ago when I used it; so you could use something like `wethr` (snap) to get details saving to a file (maybe run via `cron` job) and use conky to just output that file data on screen.  (if using `wethr` it needs write access in current directory to run; and uses symbols that I don't know how conky would handle as I only used simple text files)

Comment: This is the theme https://www.deviantart.com/speedracker/art/Smooth-Conky-V3-Made-for-Conky-Manager-2-2-461461882 , thank you very much for all the responses. I already created an account on openweather so I could use the api key and all, but the problem is that I have no idea at all about how to pull data from the site :facepalm: the little I get to understand is that the code gets some 'yweather' variable from the site and depending on the string, it displays a different icon from a folder included in the theme.

Comment: This is how i actually have it set up https://pastebin.com/cPVfK3Fn , changed BATT for BAT0 to correctly display my battery percentage and added bold to a few parts of the text to make it more visible with my wallpaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit June 7, 2020

I have conky on a 4K TV now so there is ample space to expand the height with weather information.

It is very important to select a mono spaced font that supports arrow signs for wind direction. I choose **GE Inspira Mono** 12 point but had to restore to **Ubuntu** 10.5 point afterwards:

```
#------------+
# Brightness |
#------------+
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
${color1}${goto 5}Sun Rise: ${color green}${execpi 300 cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunrise} ${goto 175}${color1}Set: ${color green}${execpi 300 cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunset} ${alignr}${color1}Level: ${color green}${execpi 10 cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness}
#------------+
# Weather    |
#------------+
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
#${font GE Inspira Mono:size=12}${alignc}${color green}${execpi 300 curl wttr.in/Edmonton?T0 --silent --max-time 3}${font ubuntu:size=10.5}
${font Dejavu Sans Mono:size=12}${alignc}${color green}${execpi 300 curl wttr.in/Edmonton?T0 --silent --max-time 3}${font ubuntu:size=10.5}
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: conky weather.png]

Yes it is unusually cold for 6 pm on June 7. Worse yet all the rain caused a 20 block power outage a couple hours ago! It was a mixed blessing because I got to install the 32 GB RAM upgrade I bought in March 2020 but was procrastinating on. System is snappier now!

**NOTE:** Sunrise and Sunset times are fake. I was testing a new function in `eyesome` today to override the daily automatic retrieval off the internet of Sun Times (aka Twilight times).

---

### Original Answer

Weather is too much information to squeeze into my conky display which is already pretty full. So instead I put it in my [terminal splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/terminal-splash-screen-with-weather-calendar-time-sysinfo/1020693#1020693):

[image: terminal splash screen.png]

You can get the same information from the command line which you can call from conky:

```
$ curl wttr.in/Edmonton?0 --silent --max-time 3

Weather report: Edmonton

     \   /     Clear
      .-.      7..8 °C        
   ― (   ) ―   → 6 km/h       
      `-’      10 km          
     /   \     0.0 mm
```

To get your city name for `wttr.in` see:

- [The right way to check the weather https://wttr.in](https://github.com/chubin/wttr.in)

---

## Display an image in conky

I saved a picture of today's weather from darksky.net and displayed it in conky with the `${image}` command:

[image: Weather in conky.png]

The relevant conky commands are:

```
#------------+
# Brightness |
#------------+
${color orange}${voffset 2}${hr 1}
${color1}${goto 5}Rise: ${color green}${execpi 300 cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunrise} ${goto 155}${color1}Set: ${color green}${execpi 300 cat /usr/local/bin/.eyesome-sunset} ${alignr}${color1}Level: ${color green}${execpi 10 cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness}

#------------+
# Image      |
#------------+
${image /home/rick/Pictures/Weather.png -p 0,1080 -s 400x120}
```

- I included the section just before for reference
- Notice all the blank lines to make conky window taller to fit in the image
- See: [Variables in Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html) for more details on `${image}` command.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about wttr.in!

Comment: I just want the weather icon and temp, like in the original theme: https://www.deviantart.com/speedracker/art/Smooth-Conky-V3-Made-for-Conky-Manager-2-2-461461882 I already managed to get the url right and the weather.xml generating correctly now what I don't understand is how conky reads xml, how the theme uses the xml or how do I get to display the weather icon from `grep "weather.number" ~/.cache/weather.xml`

Comment: Okay thats awesome, now I have a folder with all the icons from https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions, what i will try to get done is display the image using something like this `image ~/.weather-icons/$(grep "weather.icon" ~/.cache/weather.xml).png` reading the weather.xml file that I get from openweather I used the parameter weather.icon from the doc here https://openweathermap.org/current#parameter but i dont know if grep works that way, ideally what i would want is to read today's weather.icon parameter (lets say 1d) and display the image `~/.weather-icons/1d.png`

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix, in your Conky, how did you display the amount you downloaded "today", "yesterday", "week", "month"?

Comment: @Lakey Although you can display just downloaded, in this screen Conky is showing combined download and upload totals. See [vnstat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-total-internet-data-usage-across-reboots/846455#846455) program for setup.

Answer (score 1):

I was very inspired by this thread as I did not find any working Conky widget and went down to learn and create my own (based on code posted here).

Here's a widget that uses IP geolocation to identify (or guess) your rough position and display 5-day weather accordingly. Uses Big Data Cloud and Open Weather Maps APIs.

I hope it works for all of you. Simply download the file, save it to the ~/.conky directory and execute:

```
conky -c ~/.conky/Weather
```

Weather widget file:

```lua
conky.config = {
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'GE Inspira:size=16',
    xftalpha = 0.8,
    text_buffer_size = 2048,
    max_text_width = 0,
    override_utf8_locale = true,
    uppercase = false,
    no_buffers = true,
    short_units = true,
    format_human_readable = true,

    update_interval = 1,
    total_run_times = 0,

    own_window = true,
    own_window_transparent = false,
    own_window_type = 'desktop',
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
        own_window_argb_visual = true,
        own_window_argb_value = 128,
    background = true,
    use_spacer = 'none',

    double_buffer = true,
    minimum_width = 215, minimum_height = 215,

    draw_shades = false,
    default_shade_color = '#000000',

    draw_outline = false,
    default_outline_color = '#000000',

    default_color = 'FFFFFF', 
    color0 = 'FFFFFF',
    color1 = 'FFA300',

    draw_borders = false,
    stippled_borders = 0,
    border_inner_margin = 10,
    border_outer_margin = 0,
    border_width = 1,
    draw_graph_borders = false,--no
    alignment = 'top_left',

    gap_x = 107,
    gap_y = 220,

    imlib_cache_size = 0,
};


conky.text = [[
#
#REFRESH LOCATION & WEATHER INFO CACHE
${execi 600 curl -so ~/.cache/WeatherLoc 'https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/ip-geolocation?localityLanguage=en&key=3131602e55a644299e1372eaa28f3fe5'&& printf "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=%s&lon=%s&exclude=minutely,hourly&APPID=a6f8bedf50667be2d3764422a37077d2&units=metric" $(jq -r '.location.latitude' ~/.cache/WeatherLoc) $(jq -r '.location.longitude' ~/.cache/WeatherLoc)| xargs curl -so ~/.cache/WeatherData}
#
#REFRESH ICON CACHE
${execi 600 sleep 2 && jq -r '.current.weather[0].icon' ~/.cache/WeatherData | xargs printf "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%s@2x.png" | xargs curl -so ~/.cache/WeatherNow.png}\
${execi 600 sleep 2 && jq -r '.daily[0].weather[0].icon' ~/.cache/WeatherData | xargs printf "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%s@2x.png" | xargs curl -so ~/.cache/Weather0.png}\
${execi 600 sleep 2 && jq -r '.daily[1].weather[0].icon' ~/.cache/WeatherData | xargs printf "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%s@2x.png" | xargs curl -so ~/.cache/Weather1.png}\
${execi 600 sleep 2 && jq -r '.daily[2].weather[0].icon' ~/.cache/WeatherData | xargs printf "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%s@2x.png" | xargs curl -so ~/.cache/Weather2.png}\
${execi 600 sleep 2 && jq -r '.daily[3].weather[0].icon' ~/.cache/WeatherData | xargs printf "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%s@2x.png" | xargs curl -so ~/.cache/Weather3.png}\
${execi 600 sleep 2 && jq -r '.daily[4].weather[0].icon' ~/.cache/WeatherData | xargs printf "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/%s@2x.png" | xargs curl -so ~/.cache/Weather4.png}
#
#WEATHER NOW
${voffset -40}${color1}${execi 1 jq -r '.location.city' ~/.cache/WeatherLoc}
${color0}${execi 1 jq -r '.current.temp' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}° ${image ~/.cache/WeatherNow.png -s 70x70 -p 160,0}

#WEATHER TODAY
${color1}Today${goto 100}${color0}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[0].temp.min' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°/ ${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[0].temp.max' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°${image ~/.cache/Weather0.png -s 30x30 -p 180,83}
#
#WEATHER +1 DAY
${color1}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[1].dt' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '
{print "@" $1}' |xargs date +%a --date}${goto 100}${color0}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[1].temp.min' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°/ ${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[1].temp.max' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°${image ~/.cache/Weather1.png -s 30x30 -p 180,108}
#
#WEATHER +2 DAYS
${color1}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[2].dt' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '
{print "@" $1}' |xargs date +%a --date}${goto 100}${color0}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[2].temp.min' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°/ ${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[2].temp.max' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°${image ~/.cache/Weather2.png -s 30x30 -p 180,133}
#
#WEATHER +3 DAYS
${color1}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[3].dt' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '
{print "@" $1}' |xargs date +%a --date}${goto 100}${color0}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[3].temp.min' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°/ ${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[3].temp.max' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°${image ~/.cache/Weather3.png -s 30x30 -p 180,158}
#
#WEATHER +4 DAYS
${color1}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[4].dt' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '
{print "@" $1}' |xargs date +%a --date}${goto 100}${color0}${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[4].temp.min' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°/ ${execi 1 jq -r '.daily[4].temp.max' ~/.cache/WeatherData |awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'}°${image ~/.cache/Weather3.png -s 30x30 -p 180,183}
]];
```

Weather widget snapshot looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't remember where I got this.

I have a little script `weather.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
#AccuWeather (r) RSS weather tool for conky
#
#USAGE: weather.sh <locationcode>
#
#(c) Michael Seiler 2007

METRIC=0 #Should be 0 or 1; 0 for F, 1 for C

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo
    echo "USAGE: weather.sh <locationcode>"
    echo
    exit 0;
fi

curl -s http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp\?metric\=${METRIC}\&locCode\=$1 | perl -ne 'if (/Currently/) {chomp;/\<title\>Currently: (.*)?\<\/title\>/; print "$1"; }'
```

Then in the .conkyrc you have

`${exec [location of script]/weather.sh [zip code]}`

The end result is

[image]

Comment: any way to display the icon? something like this: https://www.deviantart.com/speedracker/art/Smooth-Conky-V3-Made-for-Conky-Manager-2-2-461461882

Comment: I don't know. My conky is text only.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've never displayed an image in conky either until I just read your comment. So I updated my conky to do just that and put it into my answer.

Comment: As far as where you got the script from it may have come from here: https://github.com/rgoomar/i3-wm-config/blob/master/weather.sh

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix impressive as usual! I'm fine with my lowly text only weather display but I learned something.

Comment: It looks like the perl parser is outdated on this answer.

Comment: @ChrisGrimmett I'm sorry that my answer that I wrote 4 years ago for a now-EOL version of Ubuntu was not to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I made a shell script that uses **wethr** snap app. This app shows weather based on your location on a terminal.

```
$ wethr
```

Asunción, Paraguay: 31C ☀️

Currently Conky doesn't handle emojis very well, so I had to use pangoview to convert the text to an image.

I use it on conky with

```
${image /tmp/weather-1000.jpg -p 95,328}
```

Add also this line, to enable images reload in conky

```
imlib_cache_flush_interval=1500,
```

Here's the script

https://github.com/alefq/helper-scripts/blob/master/bin/weather.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# requires wethr from snap store and pango1.0-tools
#
WFILE=/tmp/.weather-info-$UID
DEBUG=0

if [ -z $DISPLAY ]; then
    # probably running from crontab
    export DISPLAY=:0
fi

if [ $DEBUG -eq 0 ]; then
    /snap/bin/wethr > $WFILE 2>/dev/null
else 
    /snap/bin/wethr > $WFILE 
fi
pango-view --background=#ffffff  --font=onot -qo /tmp/weather-$UID.jpg $WFILE
```

Crontab update every 30 minutes

```
33 * * * * /opt/helper-scripts/bin/weather.sh
```

The final result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a command line tool to create weather widgets in conky using data from the openweathermap API. You can make them as simple or as complex as you want. For example, to display `Clouds: 22°` updated every 20 minutes, use:

```
${execi 1200 echo "$(weather -d main): $(weather)" }
```

There are more options available. See
[here](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ejagrg/weather) for more information.