How to display weather with Conky?
I have a problem with a Conky widget that uses the api.openweathermap.org.
The weather doesn't get displayed.

I have changed the API key and the City ID in the: ~/.conky/Acubens/scripts/weather-v2.0.sh but it didn't fix it. Edited file:
#!/bin/bash

# v2.0 Closebox73
# This script is to get weather data from openweathermap.com in the form of a json file
# so that conky will still display the weather when offline even though it doesn't up to date

# Variables
# get your city id at https://openweathermap.org/find and replace
city_id=588335

# replace with yours
api_key=fa7e6905acd7201c439480bea7d20871

# choose between metric for Celcius or imperial for fahrenheit
unit=celcius

# I'm not sure it will support all language, 
lang=en

# Main command
url="api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=${city_id}&appid=${api_key}&cnt=5&units=${unit}&lang=${lang}"
curl ${url} -s -o ~/.cache/weather.json

exit

I had also tried the fix from another post (chmod o+w ~/.cache/weather.json):  How to display weather properly with conky?
And the command output result was No such file or directory
I am quite new to Ubuntu, and I don't know what I am supposed to do.

How about one of the solutions in https://askubuntu.com/q/1190907/243321 ?
