# Error, when I go the the root sudo -s

Tags: bash, sudo

New to Linux. I'm using:

```
uname -r
5.15.0-30-generic
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

First I was trying to increase tty fonts, have edit the file: .bashrc
Used suggestion given in:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-the-text-mode-console
`sudo nano .bashrc`; to end added this lines:

```
# Set font when running in console
/bin/setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat2-Terminus32x16.psf.gz    

# Splash Calendar and time
now

# ASCII Linux distribution display
screenfetch
```

Started to get errors when starting terminal like:
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
Removed this 3 lines again so I get the original .bashrc file

Now error "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console"
no longer happened but still I got error when go the the root

```
sudo -s
Command 'now' not found, did you mean:
  command 'nsw' from snap nsw (0+git.b61ddec)
  command 'nop' from deb graphviz (2.42.2-6)
  command 'new' from deb mmh (0.4-4)
  command 'new' from deb nmh (1.7.1-11)
  command 'nox' from deb nox (2022.1.7-1)
  command 'sow' from deb ruby-hoe (3.22.1+dfsg1-2)
  command 'cow' from deb fl-cow (0.6-4.2)
  command 'nw' from deb netrw (1.3.2-3)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
Command 'screenfetch' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install screenfetch
```

Any help?

Comment: You've altered your login script to include commands `now` and `screenfetch` which are not included by default; thus adding them was in error, unless you plan on installing those packages.  The answer where you got the `now` from was a different release and isn't included by default on any system that I recall (*it's been a awhile since I used 16.04 but I doubt it was default there too*)  Where an answer for a *like* issue involves a different OS/release to yours; validate/check/adjust where necessary for your OS/release.  FYI: I think the `now` & `screenfetch` where used as example in answer

Comment: Here is the now script:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/terminal-splash-screen-with-weather-calendar-time-sysinfo and screenfetch is installed separately.

Comment: Please be carefull, and correct this command `sudo nano bashr.rs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds as if you changed the `.bashrc` of the root user rather than that file of your current user. Open that file:

```
sudoedit /root/.bashrc
```

and remove the three lines you still see there.

*Explanation*: using `sudo` changes to a shell for the root user. Hence, the shell initialization file of the root user are read and interpreted  before displaying the prompt. When using `bash`, the initialization file for an interactive terminal is `.bashrc`, thus `/root/.bashrc` for root user.

Comment: That's really worked. Thanks